# Azure Devops Server 2019 - Process template invisible

Tags: azure-devops, devops, tfs-process-template

we upgraded a TFS2017 to Azure Devops Server 2019.
We had a custom XML process template on TFS2017 that we want to migrate to inherited processes. But we cannot see this process template in the process page. We only see the inherited processes (Agile, CMMI, ...) and the basic XML templates which where migrated ("Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.3", "MSF for Agile Software Development 2013.2", ...)
There is a project with this custom template and we can update the process with WIT commands.

Does anyone know how to make this custom process visible in the process page? then we will be able to migrate it.

Comment: Has the project been migrated? Can you see the project?

Comment: Yes, the project has been migrated and we can see it. This project is still on the custom process that we can't upgrade

Comment: Since you could see the project, please try to go to the Project Settings->Overview, check the name of the Process, make sure of it is not in the process lists, and you could also use the REST API to list all the process to check if you have that process: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

Comment: On Azure Devops Server 2019, the Process is not displayed on the page "Project Settings->Overview". (I have checked on a fresh install too).
For the process list with the API, I will check.

Comment: With API, it's the same. We can't see the process in the list

Comment: I am afraid that custom process may lose or destroy data during the migration process, you may need to create a technical support ticket from Azure Portal https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/ if you have Azure support plans. Thanks for your understanding.